# Distinct query not working in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model as follow:

```
var GamePlayerSchema = new Schema({  
 game: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Game',
    required:true
},
group: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Group'
},
user: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
paymentDone: {
    type: Boolean,
    default:false
}});
```

In the above model any player can play multiple games.Show when I query the collection user with same name are shown twice if they are registered in two games.
To find distinct players I have used the query as below:

```
GamePlayer.find().distinct('user',function(err, results){

});
```

But this is not giving the distinct results. How do I achieve distinct result in mongoose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**`distinct`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db-collection-distinct) is a collection method change your query to the following:

```
GamePlayer.distinct('user', function(err, results){

});
```

Comment: I have fields to populate and other things like skipping and limiting how do I do that

Comment: @DeepakBhattarai [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/)